# How do I render a URLField nicely in a template

Tags: django, django-templates

**The problem**

I have a model for a league like

```
class League(models.Model):
    league_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    league_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, default='')
```

where `league_url` can be a link to an external league page (i.e. not my site).

Now, let's say a user creates a league and sets league_url to "pelicanpark.com/leagues/27".  When I render this in a template, `{{ league.league_url }}` it shows `http://www.pelicanpark.com/leagues/27/` which takes up a lot of real estate.

So, I need to slim it down.  My thought is to render something like

```
<a href="http://www.pelicanpark.com/leagues/27/">pelicanpark.com/...</a>
```

but this has some obvious complexities.  Does anyone have a good solution for this?

Comment: by ... do you mean you want  `pelicanpark.com/...` or `pelicanpark.com/leagues/27/`?

Comment: Good question.  I mean `pelicanpark.com/...`

Comment: Can you expand more on the complications by doing the following in the template?  `<a href="{{ league.league_url }}">pelicanpark.com/...</a>` wherein league is the user's league instance passed to the template. That seem like it would be the easiest?

Comment: @Ben pelicanpark.com is just an example url.  In reality the league_url could be anything.  E.g. if the url was "myleaguesite.com/leagues/123" I'd want to display `<a href="{{ league.league_url }}">myleaguesite.com/...</a>`.  In other words, the "domain.com/..." should be rendered dynamically depending on the actual league_url.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably some fancy way of using [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for this kind of thing, but that's above my head. Luckly it looks like there's [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) for python. To implement it in your example:

```
from urlparse import urlparse

class League(models.Model):
    league_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    league_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, default='')

    def url_text(self):
        parsed_url = urlparse(self.league_url)
        return parsed_url.hostname.replace("www.", "") + "/..."
```

Then in template:

```
<a href="{{ league.league_url }}">{{ league.url_text }}</a>
```

I would refrain from rendering the html in the backend. I've always been told there's security risks in doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a field with `MethodSerializer`

```
class League(models.Model):
    league_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    nice_league_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()


    def get_league_url(self,obj):
        final_url = "<a href="+obj.league_url+">pelicanpark.com/...</a>"
        return final_url
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are spot on. I just ran into the same problem and found some changes. For Python3 and higher, use:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
```

instead.